# Reversing Of Intergers(take Input from user and Reverse it)

Tags: dart, integer, reverse, helper

I want To build a Program in which i want Multiple inputs in integers and Reverse it .. how Can I Do that in Dart?

I tried of strings But Don't Know About Integers

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('Input integers (q to stop):');
  final integers = <int>[];
  while (true) {
    // Reads input from the user.
    final input = stdin.readLineSync()!;

    // Check to see if the user is done inputting numbers.
    if (input == 'q') {
      break;
    }
    // Try to convert the String to an int. If input isn't a
    // valid integer, int.tryParse(input) == null.
    final integer = int.tryParse(input);
    if (integer != null) {
      integers.add(integer);
    }
  }
  print('Original order: $integers');
  // Reversing a List in Dart is simple: just call integers.reverse
  // to get an Iterable with the elements of integers in reversed order.
  // Calling integers.reverse.toList() will convert the Iterable to a List
  // so it's possible to print the entire list at once.
  print('Reversed order: ${integers.reversed.toList()}');
}
```

Example:

```
Input integers (q to stop):
1
2
3
r
4
5
q
Original order: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Reversed order: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```